# Specifying a RouteValue to match pattern /id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, maproute

I am using asp.net mvc2 and would like my site to show details (of 123) if a user enters foo.com/123.
What is the route value I should specify for this, and in what order?
I tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "foobar",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "foo", action = "bar", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but I get a 404.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

routes.MapRoute( name: "foobar", url: "{id}", defaults: new { controller = "foo", action = "bar", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );

should be as follows

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "foo", action = "bar", id = ""// Parameter defaults

            );
```